# Pass model to child components as reference or create global variable

Tags: javascript, mvvm, dojo, single-page-application

I have SPA built using dojo with structure like:

```
App    
- > Parent Component
    - > Child component
        - > Child component
```

For my Parent component I defined model and create instace of it in component's constructor.

Now in my parent component I create instances of children like this:

```
const tabs = [
            new Head({model: model}),
            new Main({model: model}),
            new Statement({model: model})
        ];
```

So I access model in children components with `this` keyword.

Wouldn't it be better to create instance of model for current component in some global namespace and access it in all child components like `app.model` or just global variable `model` just to avod of passing reference through cascade of nested components?

Which approach is better an why?

Comment: Sounds like there might be an underlying architectural problem. Probably related to your "model" being something like a "god object" .... but I'm just guessing.

Comment: @tereško I'm trying to implement something, which looks like mvvm pattern, and I have a view, but it's too complex to put in one file. So I've splitted it into smaller components, but I'd like them to share one "viewmodel".

Comment: a global variable would be bad practice.  you can create a singleton class for your model.  initialize it once at application startup and every time you require it in your other modules, it will return the same instance.